# Selenium C# How do I inspect an element which opens a pop up dialog. I think it may be a JavaScript event

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text value from an element from a web page.  I have the username field, password field and the Go button (Submit) elements.
I leave the username and password field blank and I click the Go button.
A pop up field displays just below the username field and the text value is "Please fill out this field"

I would like to capture the text "Please fill out this field" and then I can do an assert on it to verify this text has displayed.
The url is https://inplay.betway.com

I am not able to inspect the element of this pop up.  It could be a JavaScript event that triggers this pop up to display.

If i inspect the Go button the HTML is:

```
    <div id="login" class="right">
<form id="loginForm">
    <div class="loginInputs">
    <div class="loginSubmit">
        <input class="loginbutton" value="Go" type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"/>
</form>
    <div id="loginError" class="hide">
    <div class="loginErrorText"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"/>
```

How do i get the text value from the element?
I am using Selenium C#

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Is the pop-up a frame or an alert? You use `ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent` and similar checks, if it is an alert. [Check out the docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm).

Comment: And if it is an alert, then I don't think you can get the text of it. However, that's not something that an automated check is best used for, anyway. Don't assert on static strings like that. You can verify that by eye, once. Checking it every time you commit a change won't increase anyone's confidence that your application is working. Concentrate on checking stuff that computers are good at checking, and that increases your confidence that your application is working.

Comment: My automated bdd scenario is to check the user is not able to log in with invalid user credentials.  As it displays a pop up on the invalid log in I was going to use that to verify the test has passed.

Comment: The behaviour is something like "Given a valid user James, When James enters Invalid credentials, Then the he is not logged in"? Then check only that James is not logged in. The alert/popup is an implementation detail, don't use it in any assertions. Check only that the logged in state of James is "not logged in". Best to check it using an API or DB state too: if you're performing an action through the UI, it's best not to assert on UI state afterwards. It's too easy for the UI to report the wrong thing.

Comment: I understand now, I will discuss it with my colleagues in the morning.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you need an argument: what if there's a developer decision to change the alert to an in-page warning, and drop the alert (this will happen, everyone hates alerts)? You don't want to have to fix your test even though nothing has changed from a behavioural point of view. The user is still not logged in. The test should still pass.

Comment: @RiazLadhani If you found a solution i would be interested to know how you did it